# App crash on startup with only update not fresh install

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, ios6

I have a strange issue with my latest version on App store. Some users report that the app crash on startup after upgrading the app and it only happens with iOS6. However, the crash will not happen if the user delete the app and have a fresh install.

I check the crash log on the phone and see this error.

```
OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A403)

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN at 0x2fe6f785
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   My App                          0x00074ace +[aClass sharedNormalImages] (aClass.m:34)
1   dyld                            0x2fe79628 ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 16
2   dyld                            0x2fe76a3a ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 382
3   dyld                            0x2fe76874 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 36
4   dyld                            0x2fe6dd04 dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 172
5   dyld                            0x2fe7085c dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 1804
6   dyld                            0x2fe6d32c dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 604
7   dyld                            0x2fe6d064 _dyld_start + 60
```

The sharedNormalImages function has not been changed at all from the recent version and it is just a function that return an array like this.

```
static NSArray *normalImages = nil;
+ (NSArray *)sharedNormalImages
{
     if (normalImages == nil) {
             normalImages = @[@"xx.png", @"xy.png", @"yx.png", @"yy.png"];
     }

     return normalImages;
}
```

I really have no idea what happen. I tried to install with the old version and then replace with the new version with Xcode. The problem also does not happen. So I cannot replicate it with my environment at all. That is so strange.

**Edit**

Not sure how it could be related but I see this error message on the device console.

```
Oct 19 12:36:16 iPhone My App[210] <Error>: objc[210]: Class  is implemented in both /var/mobile/Applications/A5EC61E7-7DBA-4FA5-A5FE-6D49EAFAD6EB/My App.app/My App and /var/mobile/Applications/A5EC61E7-7DBA-4FA5-A5FE-6D49EAFAD6EB/My App.app/My App. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Oct 19 12:36:16 iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[210] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Oct 19 12:36:16 iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[210] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/A5EC61E7-7DBA-4FA5-A5FE-6D49EAFAD6EB (sandbox)
Oct 19 12:36:16 iPhone ReportCrash[211] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process My App[210]
Oct 19 12:36:16 iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.acompany.myapp[0x813f][210]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.acompany.myapp[0x813f]) Job appears to have crashed: Bus error: 10
Oct 19 12:36:16 iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.acompany.myapp[0x813f]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.acompany.myapp[0x813f]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483647 seconds
Oct 19 12:36:16 iPhone backboardd[52] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.acompany.myapp[0x813f]' exited abnormally with signal 10: Bus error: 10
Oct 19 12:36:16 iPhone ReportCrash[211] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Oct 19 12:36:16 iPhone ReportCrash[211] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/My App_2012-10-19-123616_iPhone.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

FYI, I update the app icon to be "prerendered" on the latest update but I don't think that could make the crash.

Comment: have you tried normalImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"xx.png", @"xy.png", @"yx.png", @"yy.png",nil]; ?

Comment: The problem is cannot reproduce it with my machine now. Anyway, if this is really the problem, why it happens only with iOS6 not iOS5?

Comment: Hi Do you have any change in Coredata, in your app?

Comment: I don't use coredata in my app.

Comment: Are there multiple executables in the binaries? Did you change the executable name? That `Class  is implemented in both` is very irritating and shouldn't be there. The original crash reports also suggests that there is problem loading data from the executable.

Comment: @Kerni Only 2 things I have changed in build settings are the version number and selecting "Prerendered" in App icons setting. Would that make the binaries duplicated?

Comment: Before finding the cause of a problem, it is important to understand what the problem actually is. So you need to understand the error messages and crash reports. And those imply that it is somehow confused by finding multiple executables, see the 1st line in the console log. So try to find out if there are multiple executables on those devices in the app paths. You can use tools like PhoneView or iExplorer to check that on the devices.

Comment: @Kerni I wonder how it could be 2 executables because it route to the same path? => /var/mobile/Applications/A5EC61E7-7DBA-4FA5-A5FE-6D49EAFAD6EB/My App.app/My App and /var/mobile/Applications/A5EC61E7-7DBA-4FA5-A5FE-6D49EAFAD6EB/My App.app/My App

Answer (score 1):

To replicate the issue, try following steps:

1. build both the versions using Ad-Hoc Provisioning profile,
2. install older version using iTunes.
3. open the app on device and go through all the views.
4. update with new version of app using iTunes and run

Comment: I'm sorry but I forgot to put a line on top.  `static NSArray *normalImages = nil;`

Comment: I have seen some weirdness with some of the new ways of defining constant arrays, but I think @ShineethHamza may be on to something. While the two code lines may conceptually be the same, they mean different things to the compiler and may be causing the issue. It's not about access, I think it's about how it's being created, stored and referenced. It may even be a bug. I would try it if you haven't yet.

Comment: @ThuggishNuggets i have wrote that answer before he added `static NSArray *normalImages = nil;` to the question. Sorry about that, my apologies. i edited the answer. thank bro.

Comment: I just tried this from @ShineethHamza's advise. It does not crash after upgrading to the new version.